# Rails - Submitting Nested Values That Already Exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a model, Tran that has a foreign key to the User model.  In the view for creation a Tran (transaction), I have a dropdown that allows the user to select the User that started the transaction.  When I post this transaction, the record is set with the correct user ID:

Then, in my Trans model I added "belongs_to", as I understand I should do this for foreign keys:

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :buying_user, :class_name => 'User'
```

Now, when my client passes up the params in the post, my Tran.new craps out because I am passing up a userID and not a full record.  Is the

```
#trans_controller.rb
def create
    @title = "Create Transaction"
        #bombs on this call
    @tran = Tran.new(params[:tran])
```

How am I supposed to handle this?

Update as requested:
tran.rb

```
class Tran < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :transaction_users, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'TransactionUser'
    belongs_to :submitting_user, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :buying_user, :class_name => 'User'

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :transaction_users, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:content].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true

    validates :description, :presence => true,
                            :length => {:maximum => 100 }
    validates :total,       :presence => true
    validates_numericality_of :total, :greater_than => 0

    validates :submitting_user,         :presence => true           
    validates :buying_user,             :presence => true   

    validates_associated :transaction_users

end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :trans
    attr_accessor :password
    attr_accessible :firstname, :lastname, :email, :password, :password_confirmation

    email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i


    validates :firstname, :presence => true,
                            :length => {:maximum => 50 }
    validates :lastname, :presence => true,
                            :length => {:maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true,
                            :format => {:with => email_regex },
                            :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false }

    validates :password, :presence => true,
                            :confirmation => true,
                            :length => { :within => 6..40 }

    # Register callback to before save so that we can call extra code like password encryption                      
    before_save :encrypt_password

    # Class methods
    def self.authenticate(email, submitted_password)
        user = find_by_email(email)
        return nil if user.nil?
        return user if user.has_password?(submitted_password)
    end

    def self.authenticate_with_salt(id, cookie_salt)
        user = find_by_id(id)
        (user && user.salt == cookie_salt) ? user : nil
    end

    # Public methods

    def has_password?(submitted_password)
        self.encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
    end

    def full_name 
        "#{self.lastname}, #{self.firstname}"
    end

    def self.active_users
        # TODO
        #User.find_
        User.all

    end


    private

        def encrypt_password
            self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
            self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
        end

        def encrypt (string)
            secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
        end

        def make_salt
            secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
        end

        def secure_hash(string)
            Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
        end
end
```

params hash on submit:

```
{"commit"=>"Submit",
 "tran"=>{"total"=>"100",
 "submitting_user"=>"1",
 "description"=>"Description"},
 "authenticity_token"=>"88qI+iqF92fo/M9rPfMs1CLpEXqFLGQXfj0c9krXXac=",
 "utf8"=>"âœ“",
 "user"=>"1"}
```

error:

```
User(#70040336455300) expected, got String(#70040382612480)
```

beginning of controller:

```
def create
    @title = "Create Transaction"
    @tran = Tran.new(params[:tran])
```

It crashes on the Tran.new line. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!  The problem the whole time was that my db column name on my Trans table that linked to my Users table was `submitting_user` instead of `submitting_user_id`.  Then, when I added the belongs_to association to `submitting_user` rails got confused and made that field a User, instead of an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the User model would have `has_many :transactions, :class_name => Tran`
Then you would do this...

```
@user.transaction_create(params[:tran])
or
@user.build
```

it depends on what parameters are actually passed in params[:tran], but the idea is that the has_many side does the creating of the belongs_to.

Comment: @Jim Morris - my table actually has two users that have FKs like this, so I couldn't just call transaction_create off of one of them.

Comment: do you mean that the Tran belongs to two different users? In which case it cannot be a belongs_to, but a has_and_belongs_to_many

Comment: @Jim Morris - Yes, the Trans has a SubmittingUser and a BuyingUser.  Also, I think my real problem is that I am using belongs_to without the default name.  If you notice above I have "belongs_to :submitting_user", but the model it references is user, not submitting_user.  I think this is supposed to generate a submitting_user_id for me, but it seems it isn't created.

Comment: @Jim Morris - To sum up that rambling, shouldn't I get a :submitting_user_id in the view, as suggested by http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html under "One-to-one"?

Comment: If you can add a little more detail to the question I may be able to help. Maybe the full Trans model, the User model and exactly what the params are in the controller when you try to create a Trans.

Comment: @Jim Morris - I have edited the question - I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Jim Morris - thanks for all of your help.  I have solved the problem and +1ed your answer.